# SPServices CAMLQuery Skip some rows

Tags: spservices

I want to Skip some records and get other records in SPServices CAML Query

for example my List has got 100 records,
I want to skip first 20 records and get 10 records.

how do I do it in SPServices, I want to implement paging in my List using SPServices.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not work like SQL so you do not have Limit and Offset values like you have in SQL.

To do it using SPServices you can follow this link
[Paging using SPServices](https://thomasdaly.net/2011/03/31/using-spservices-and-pagination-to-create-a-photo-gallery/)

You can also do pagination without using SPServices which uses PageSize and PagePosition to track items

[Paging With Sharepoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx)

Comment: I already visited that link you posted: (https://thomasdaly.net/2011/03/31/using-spservices-and-pagination-to-create-a-photo-gallery/) but that link has not included the JS file and not provided full code.

Comment: Did you visited this link here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24839514/TomBlogFiles/gallery.zip  It is provided in the same site

Comment: Yes that is not working too